# How to create an object array with child items without duplicated values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
initialArray = ["a", "b", "c". "d.e", "d.e.f", "d.e.g", "d.h.i", "d.h.j"]
```

But I want this array like this or the closest as possible:

```
finalArray: [
                    { "a": [] },
                    { "b": [] },
                    { "c": [] },
                    { "d": [
                            { "e": [ "f", "g" ] },
                            { "h": [ "i", "j" ] }
                        ] },
                ]
```

The values of `initialArray` are randomly assigned. The values and the length of the comma separated strings can be changed (there can be more or less letters in those strings), so that I need a general idea to build that `finalArray`. I'd really be appreciated if someone can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you get from `initialArray` to `finalArray`?

Comment: Are you sure? That array with objects with only *one* key makes little sense ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` in `forEach` loop to create an array for each path and then use `reduce` method to create nested structure.

```js
const data = ["a", "b", "c", "d.e", "d.e.f", "d.e.g", "d.h.i", "d.h.j"]

const result = []
const level = { result }

data.forEach(str => {
  str.split('.').reduce((r, e) => {
    if (!r[e]) {
      r[e] = {result: []}
      r.result.push({[e]: r[e].result})
    }
    return r[e]
  }, level)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a left-skewed binary tree or a linked list kind of problem. If there is a dot after the current character, use that as an indicator that node `.next()` or `.left()` exists. You'd need to manually check for duplicates, i.e, check if the current char, e.g, 'e': finalArray->d->e exists, if so, just append to its values, otherwise, create a new array. That's how I'd approach it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to create an object. But I don't know what you really want to do...

```
var obj = new Object();

// add a key named myKey with value "myValue"
obj["myKey"] = "myValue";  

// add a dynamic key with a dynamic value
var key = "something", 
val = "something"; 

obj[key] = val;

// read value 
val = obj["myKey"];
```